# Detecting "Verbals" in Natural Language

Tags: python, text, nlp, spacy, text-mining

Is there any way in python to detect verbals. Verbals are words formed from a verb, but functioning as a different part of speech e.g. "priced" in "the product is fresh , delicious , and reasonably priced". [1]

When the following code is run in spacy the word "priced" is rightfully detected as a verb, however is there any of of being able to detect it as a non normal verb i.e. verbal

```
for token in nlp("the product is fresh , delicious , and reasonably priced"):
    print(token, token.pos_)
```

[1] retrieved from https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2014/task4/data/uploads/semeval14_absa_annotationguidelines.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.tag_` instead of `.pos_` you'll get `VBN`, which is a past participle tag. The tags are based on the [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).